# Fill Keys and values of a Dictionary<K, V> using arrays in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, variable-assignment

I have two equally sized arrays, **arrayKeys** and **arrayValues** filled with data, respectively for Keys and Values, and an empty `Dictionary<K, V>`(**myDictionary**). I would like to assign as Keys and Values of the Dictionary the elements in each array. I know that this can be done by using the following code:

```
for(i=0:i<arrayKeys.Lenght;i++)
{
   myDictionary.Add(arrayKeys[i], arrayValue[i]);
}
```

but I would like to know whether is there any way to perform the assignment as follows:

```
myDictionary.Keys = arrayKeys;
myDictionary.Values = arrayValues;
```

maybe by using lambdas with the ToDictionary method. Thanks in advance

Francesco

Comment: myDictionary.Keys, myDictionary.Values are just getters, so you could not assign it to some value.

Comment: @Abdul Muqtadir: I used those instructions just to give an idea about what I want to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write

```
myDictionary = keys.Zip(values, (k, v) => new { k, v })
                   .ToDictionary(o => o.k, o => o.v);
```

Comment: +1 - [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) is .NET 4 only, though

Comment: thanks for your answer. I target .NET 4 so it is no problem to use Zip. I didn't know this method, really useful and concise

Answer (score 4):

You can't assign them directly, but you can use some variant of:

```
var myDict = arrayKeys.Select((item, i) => new { Key = item, Value = arrayValues[i] })
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that.

Because of the way that `Dictionary` works, you have to insert each `KeyValuePair<K, V>` at the same time (since the location of the value is determined by the hash of the key).

Comment: I used those instructions just to give an idea about what I want to do